# ReactJS: using localStorage to save data breaks with error Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a component Home that I can render in different ways depending on the state.

I am trying to set the state of Home from localStorage

```js
/*
The AuthContext


const globalState = {
  email: null,
  token: null
};
*/

export default function Home() {

  const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
    const email = localStorage.getItem('email') || null;
    setUser({email, token});
  })

}
```

This error keeps popping up though and I don't know how to solve it

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect

I tried removing the useEffect but another error popped up

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate

I know that this error is caused by calling the setUser repeatedly.

But I am not sure how to call the setUser only once.

Comment: just add an empty dependency array, it will work like componentDidMount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useEffect()` is called whenever the item renders, and setting the state causes the component to re-render. Add an empty dependencies arrays to the `useEffect` block. This will allow to block to run only on initial render.

```
const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthContext);
useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
  const email = localStorage.getItem('email') || null;
  setUser({email, token});
}, [])
```

Since this should happen only once, and the `useState` is a bit redundant, you can get the same result with `useMemo` instead. This is a bit less idiomatic, because getting data from `localStorage` is a side effect, but it's simpler in a case like this.

```
const user = useMemo(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
  const email = localStorage.getItem('email') || null;
  
  return { email, token };
}, [])
```

Comment: Note: useEffect is also called when `props` changes.

Comment: It's called when the props change or the state changes according to it's dependencies array. No dependency array - all changes. Empty array - none. And if the array has values, shallow compare to the prev values.